# Is it possible to change the exit code in a function registered with atexit()?

Tags: c, exit-code, atexit

The man page for [`atexit(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) says the following:

> POSIX.1-2001 says that the result of calling `exit(3)` more than once (i.e., calling `exit(3)` within a function registered using `atexit()`) is undefined. On some systems (but not Linux), this can result in an infinite recursion; portable programs should not invoke `exit(3)` inside a function registered using `atexit()`.

However, I'm interested in modifying the exit code in a finalizer for my program. The only way I've managed to do this is by calling `exit()` from within my finalization function, but the man page explicitly warns against that.

Is there any practical danger against doing this? Are there any implementations where that approach might cause problems? Even better, is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call [`_exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit) instead.

Within the Notes section of the man page:

> The function `_exit()` is like `exit()`, but does not  call  any  functions registered with `atexit()` or `on_exit()`.

This should avoid the "recursive" issue that is being warned about in the POSIX spec. If you are somehow able to guarantee that your "exit code changing" exit handler runs last, this should work perfectly, modulo the caveats also listed in the Notes:

> Whether it flushes standard I/O buffers and removes temporary files created with `tmpfile(3)` is implementation-dependent. On the other hand, `_exit()` does close open file descriptors, and this may cause an unknown delay, waiting for pending output to finish. If the delay is undesired, it may be useful to call functions like `tcflush(3)` before calling `_exit()`. Whether any pending I/O is canceled, and which pending I/O may be canceled upon `_exit()`, is implementation-dependent.